# Whenever we use seekbar on cardview how to stop seekbar to get into focus on when cardview have clickable true attribute

Tags: android-layout

When click on cardview, seek bar is get into focus, when cardview have clickable "true" attribute.

```xml
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cardview"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/darkGray"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekbar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:max="360"
        android:progressBackgroundTint="@color/white"
        android:progressTint="@color/white" />

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

When I use clickable true property in cardview , after click anywhere on cardview seekbar is get in foucus. But when I remove that property map drags and moves because cardview is on MapView.

Cardview is on Mapview so mapview should not be clicked when I click on cardview and seekbar should not get in focus.

Comment: Have you tried to set `focusable` and `focusableInTouchMode` properties to false when you use the `clickable` property of `CardView`?

Comment: Yes I have tried but not working.

Comment: Can you add some images that illustrate the case and the code where you modify seekbar and cardview?